# Qt keeping mouse centered

Tags: qt, fixed, mouse-cursor

I'm wondering if anyone has a trick to keep the mouse position centered in a (QGL)widget for Qt. I read that one could set the mouseposition after finding the delta, but this way works very buggy for me. Mouse events are not properly registered, any if they do, very jumpy.

```
void World::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) {

        GLfloat dx = GLfloat(event->x() - lastPos.x()) / width();
        GLfloat dy = GLfloat(event->y() - lastPos.y()) / height();

        player->rotHorizontal += 360.0 * dx;
        if(player->rotHorizontal < 0.0)
            player->rotHorizontal += 360.0;
        else if(player->rotHorizontal > +360.0)
            player->rotHorizontal -= 360.0;

        player->rotVertical += 360.0 * dy;

        if (player->rotVertical > MAX_ROTATION_UP) {
            player->rotVertical = MAX_ROTATION_UP;
        } else if (player->rotVertical < -MAX_ROTATION_UP) {
            player->rotVertical = -MAX_ROTATION_UP;
        }

    }
//    int diffX = event->pos().x() - lastPos.x() % 20;
//    int diffY = event->pos().y() - lastPos.y() % 20;
//    if (diffY > 10 || diffX > 10 || diffY < -10 || diffX < -10) {
//        QPoint glob = mapToGlobal(QPoint(this->pos().x() + width()/2, this->pos().y() + height()/2));
//        QCursor::setPos(glob);
//    }
    lastPos = event->pos();
    QGLWidget::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}
```

I commented out the code which would keep the mouse centered. If this would work, I would place it in the leftclick area.

Comment: People tend to frown on applications that 'steal' their cursor, can you elaborate on why you want to do this?  There is probably a better solution.

Comment: It's an application with a GUI, however one of the widgets needs the mouse to not touch the edges of the screen, like a first person shooter ie, always stay centered.

Comment: But how does the user leave the widget once entered? Also first person shooters hide the cursor, and use the mouse movement delta.  I use a QGLWidget for displaying CAD data, the user uses the mouse to navigate through the scene, and mouse events are given to me every pixel change (wrt. refresh rate).  So a better question would be why are your mouse events not dense?  Are you overriding the `QWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent* event)`?

Comment: I uploaded my mouse code, as you can see I update the "player" position every mousemoveevent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed:

```
void World::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) {

        GLfloat dx = GLfloat(event->x() - lastPos.x()) / width();
        GLfloat dy = GLfloat(event->y() - lastPos.y()) / height();

        player->rotHorizontal += 360.0 * dx;
        if(player->rotHorizontal < 0.0)
            player->rotHorizontal += 360.0;
        else if(player->rotHorizontal > +360.0)
            player->rotHorizontal -= 360.0;

        player->rotVertical += 360.0 * dy;

        if (player->rotVertical > MAX_ROTATION_UP) {
            player->rotVertical = MAX_ROTATION_UP;
        } else if (player->rotVertical < -MAX_ROTATION_UP) {
            player->rotVertical = -MAX_ROTATION_UP;
        }

    }
    QPoint glob = mapToGlobal(QPoint(width()/2,height()/2));
    QCursor::setPos(glob);
    lastPos = QPoint(width()/2,height()/2);
    QGLWidget::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: But how do you prevent the `mouseMoveEvent` from be called again when you invoke `QCursor::setPos`? I tried something similar and have the problem that it just will cause the controls to "wiggle" because every movement is instantly reversed.

Comment: Sorry, it's been so long I worked on this I can't remember having an issue with that at all. It might be that the Qt framework changed and introduced that issue.